# Would a regex lookaround work to match one or two numbers?

Tags: c#, regex

I am taking in a user input (string) and checking it against 3 different reg ex patterns.  The reason for this is we are doing asynchronous validation and the validation function is firing on every key up.  The user input string concatenations, so is longer with each iteration.

The regex should match 1 to 3 digit numbers, then a space, then again 1 to 3 digit numbers. Examples:

```
Correct: 
1 
12
12 26
123 12

Incorrect
any letter or spec character
any space before a number (space after first set of numbers is ok).
```

The following function works:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        List<string> patternList = new List<string>();
        patternList.Add(@"^([0-9])$");
        patternList.Add(@"^[0-9]{1,3} $");
        patternList.Add(@"^[0-9]{1,3} [0-9]{1,3}$");

        ValidateInput(userInput, patternList);
    }

    private static void ValidateInput(string userInput, List<string> patternList)
    {
        Regex r = null;
        Match m = null;
        bool IsMatch = false;
        foreach (var p in patternList)
        {
            r = new Regex(p);
            m = r.Match(userInput);
            IsMatch = m.Success;
            if (IsMatch)
                break;
        }                       

        if (IsMatch)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You wrote: {0} Thats a match", userInput);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You wrote: {0} Thats NOT a match", userInput);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

But I am looking to see if one expression (instead of 3) can be used. Would lookarounds, like a negative look behind later in the expression to make sure there is a number preceding the space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need lookaround at all, you can simply compress the three regexes into a single one:

```
^([0-9]{1,3})(?: ([0-9]{1,3})?)?$
```

`?:` means it is a non-capture group, so the first matching group will capture the first number, and the second capture group evidently the second.

In case the space sequence between the two numbers is arbitrary (one or more spaces, tabs, whatever), you can also use:

```
^([0-9]{1,3})(?:\s+([0-9]{1,3})?)?$
```

instead.

Lookahead and lookbehind can evidently be used, but are making things way more complicated and harder to parse. Furthermore, lookahead is in many cases used for the **and** pattern, not the **or** pattern. The **or** pattern can also be implemented with the disjunction (`|`).

Comment: The one flaw in the expression is that it will fail for the input: "123 ", with a space at the end, right before the user types the second set of numbers.

Comment: @Colin: euh can you provide the input, or is the input empty? By putting it between backquotes special characters are visible...

Comment: @Colin: that's the second regex pattern. I find it odd as well. Otherwise the input would be simpler.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was focusing on the original expression (which, in my defense, was the only one when I first looked at the answer). :-)

Comment: @Colin: nor the first, nor the second will fail I think. They [accept](https://regex101.com/r/fU3qG4/1) the input. Because of the space is higher in the expression tree than the second digit.

Comment: I thought the v1 answer I saw (before your edits) was different (I posted my answer 23 seconds after yours and glanced at it then), but maybe not.

Comment: @Colin: well the weird thing is, that the *edit* history of the answer is not available... It is however possible I made a small edit. If one works concurrently on multiple answers, one loses track of the edits.

Comment: Thank you both, this is working perfectly.  Can you recommend a good reference?  My reference includes ?, but does not include ?:

Comment: @BattlFrog: [this link](http://www.rexegg.com/) is a complete tutorial on regexes, with [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#noncap) the non-capture group.

Comment: This is also an awesome reference (and the one I go back to most often):
http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Info about captures and groups here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: Thanks, these will surely help!

Answer (score 1):

This one expression would validate the input as they type (no lookaround needed).

```
^[0-9]{1,3}(?:\s[0-9]{0,3})?$
```

Comment: @Bas: if you look to the regexes, the third pattern matches this as well...: `[0-9]{1,3} [0-9]{1,3}`, so that's correct.

Comment: @CommuSoft sorry my bad